# Properly format data for analysis in Power BI

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

Edit: I reformatted the question and images here:
[Table Formatting in Power BI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77949432/table-formatting-in-power-bi)

The table comes in with a format as seen here:

[image]

I need the format to be all the test names as their own column headers with another column for Value where Value1, Value2, etc. would be. My main struggle with just transposing it is there are thousands of rows and each test name is repeated at least hundreds of times. I'd be looking for just 1 column for each test name.

Here is the desired format:

[image]

There are also corresponding ID values that would need to line up with it.

I'm very new to Power BI (I typically use JMP), so have really only tried transposing, but I don't see the same options that are available in JMP (i.e. transpose columns by, labels, etc.)

Comment: potentially you want to right click fist column then unpivot other columns but you really need to edit your question to show a sample desired output

Comment: Where are the ID values in the table?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Table Formatting in Power BI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77949432/table-formatting-in-power-bi)

Answer (score 0):

In Power Query (select `Transform data` in the main PBI window, in the Home tab), try the following:

1. **Transpose**: In the Transform tab in the ribbon, you'll find `Transpose` in the first group named "Table".
2. **Use first row as headers**: In the Transform tab in the ribbon, select `Use first row as headers`, in the first group named "Table".

Comment: There are actually thousands of rows with test names repeated multiple times and I'd only want 1 column for each. Sorry, forgot to add that to my question; I will edit it.

Answer (score 0):

I will just go ahead and assume your data looks like data on top here, repeating every XXX rows, and you want to get to bottom. In powerquery, you can paste this into home...advanced editor... using your first row in place of mine

[image]

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Index1" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index1", "Custom", each if Text.Contains([Column1],"24 Hr") then [Index] else null),
#"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Added Custom",{"Custom"}),
#"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filled Down",{"Index"}),
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Removed Columns1", {"Column1", "Custom"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", List.Distinct(#"Unpivoted Other Columns"[Column1]), "Column1", "Value", List.Sum)
in  #"Pivoted Column"
```

Comment: Thank you! However, I get the error message: Expression.Error: The column 'Column1' of the table wasn't found.
Details:
    Column1                                                                                                                                               I tried changing column1 to the header name I used and tried renaming my header to Column1 and neither of those things worked.

Comment: Sorry, that does not make a lot of sense.  If you have Column1  (upper case C, no space) then it would work the same.  Or change my code to use your name (TestName) in place of Column1 in the three locations that I reference Column1.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help here any more.  Feel free do edit your question to paste in your code that you find in home...advanced editor.... along with current issue

Comment: Hi, thank you. Yeah, I'm not sure why it's not working properly; could it be due to the what comes before I put your code in? I will add what it looks like before adding yours to the question.